# Measuring Node Provisioning and Pod Scheduling Times with Prometheus/Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks, promql, karpenter

I have 5 m5.xlarge nodes. When I create a new pod that cannot be scheduled on these nodes due to CPU/memory constraints, the cluster-autoscaler/karpenter triggers the creation of a new node, and the pod is then scheduled to this new node. I'm looking to use Prometheus/Grafana to measure the time taken for:

Node creation,
Pod scheduling on the new node, and
The pod reaching a 'Ready' status.

I attempted to calculate this using the formula timestamp(kube_pod_status_unschedulable{pod="podName"}) - timestamp(kube_pod_status_scheduled{pod="podName"}), but it hasn't worked as expected.

I except to see something like:
Pod1: 3m to be scheduled
Pod2: 2m24s to be scheduled
etc

Comment: And if if possible, I want to see only the pods that were scheduled to newly created nodes.
I mean, if the pod was created, and scheduler was able to schedule it to the already existing node, ignore this.